# Mouse click-and-drag not working when on Extend Display mode

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10, version 21H2

**Issue**: Cannot click-and-drag mouse ONLY when on Extend(ed) Display (from one of the Windows + P display modes). The truth is that the mouse just overall acts weird - the middle click does not work normally as in it cannot open a link in a new tab, etc. I just thought the click-and-drag issue to be the most problematic as it effectively prevents me from opening stuff on the non-main displays.

I have been using Extended Display without issue since 2 years ago on 2 monitors connected via HDM and DVI to my GTX 1050 ti. Then I added a regular LCD TV around 3 weeks ago. Perhaps this was to blame? Though even though I remove it, the issue persists as long as I'm on Extended mode. I wasn't sure what changed or what update caused it since I really didn't notice when it started (and at the back of my head I believe I have been experiencing it prior to adding the TV). It's curious that this only happens on such display mode - once you switch to the others, mouse works okay instantly.

When restarting, I can click-and-drag *for a while* until a certain process halts it maybe.

As a side note, I can confirm the clicks actually register when testing them on this [online tool](https://www.onlinemictest.com/mouse-test/). So the clicks are triggered but cannot be 'held', I think.

Answer (score 0):

Running a single session of CCLEANER (Free version v6.02.9938) fixed it. Unfortunately I'm not skilled enough to figure out how it actually worked. Also, my quick search says I won't be able to find any logfile for the Ccleaner session which would have been useful for others who might want to dive into the details of the problem. I'll update this post once I experience it again and hopefully narrow down the cause. For now, this one's considered fixed.

PS: I think it's worth noting that I don't have any other antivirus installed other than Windows Defender. I ran Malwarebyte's free adwcleaner prior to CCleaner and that one didn't detect any malicious stuff.